# Why can I access a variable of derived class in its abstract class in Python?

Tags: python

I'm surprised that the following code runs without error.

```
# ABC
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    a = 1

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def get_scaled_a(self):
        return self.a / Bar1.a # why can I access Bar1.a?

    @abstractmethod
    def class_type(self):
          pass


# Derived class 1
class Bar1(Foo):

    a = 100

    def class_type(self):
       return 'bar1'


# Derived class 2
class Bar2(Foo):

    a = 10

    def class_type(self):
       return 'bar2'


my_bar2_inst = Bar2(0, 0)
print(my_bar2_inst.get_scaled_a())
# 0.1
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you user name is just hilarious, I'm laughing so hard.

Comment: Why would you *not* be able to access `Bar1.a`? It's not private or anything. Python doesn't even have private attributes.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `a`, but if you are using python 3, the metaclass syntax is `class Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta):`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thanks! Is there a reason why the change? I tried to find some explanations in the documentation but to no avail.

Comment: @SibbsGambling: Among other things, the new syntax means the metaclass is known before the class body is entered, allowing things like `__prepare__` to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the child class attribute for the same reason you can do this:

```
>>> class myobj: pass
>>> def f(obj):
        print(obj.a)
>>> obj1, obj2 = myobj(), myobj()
>>> obj1.a, obj2.a = 1, 2
>>> f(obj1)
1
>>> f(obj2)
2
```

Classes are just objects. Metaclasses are little more than class-object-factories.

Here's another illustration. Say I have a [`Reuben`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuben_sandwich) maker:

```
>>> Reuben = type('Reuben', (), {'mayo':False}) # <-- shortcut for making a class
```

Now say I have some kind of worthless sandwich making factory that puts mayo on everything (gross):

```
>>> def MakeMeASandwich(sandwich_type):
        sandwich_type.mayo = True
        return sandwich_type()
```

Would you expect that to work? If you said yes, you're right:

```
>>> s = MakeMeASandwich(Reuben)
# reuben with mayo!
```

Why did you expect that to work? Probably because there is no reason the function shouldn't be able to access `mayo`. It's there. It's not hidden. So of course it can get to it.

Again: a metaclass is *little more than a class making factory*. It is very much the same as any other factory (though they do have some nifty extra bells and whistles that you probably don't need).

Comment: Did you accidentally redefine `object`? You can't normally add attributes to objects whose exact type is `object`.

Comment: @user2357112 I was being flippant and careless. I'll do better. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> # Why can I access Bar.a?
> ```

Because Python assumes that developers are mature human beings. Instead of the interpreter checking whether you have access to a certain attribute, in Python you usually have **access to *all* attributes**. It is up to you to be mature enough and don't break anything.

There is however a convention that attributes starting with a lowercase, like `_foo`, `__bar` and `__qux__` are *considered* private. It means it is usually a bad idea to access those yourself. But there is no *mechanism* in place to prevent you from accessing them: the variable name more or less asks that you would be so kind not to access it. In case you absolutely need it, it is your responsibility.

Now the `a` of `Bar` is a **member of the `Bar` class**, not of a `Bar` instance. So in some other languages, it would be considered to be **"*static*"**. That's another reason why you can access it.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `get_scaled_a`, the `Bar1` class has already been defined, and so has its `a` attribute.  Remember that classes are objects too, not just class instances.  So when `Bar1` is defined, you can access certain attributes without creating an instance of it.

The fact that it is a subclass doesn't play a role at all.